# Set Text width more than Display width

Tags: android, textview, text-width

I thought that maximum width of a text View in android is display width of the device.I have scroll text that is extended from Linear Layout.By using animation class i can move the text, and its act like a automatic Scrolling text. My problem is the text length(String length 70) exceed the maximum width of the text view (1280 pixel). So the text 70 is show like this (...)

Comment: please put some code!

Comment: Can you try to clarify what you want, and add the relevant parts of your layout xml-file? If I understand correctly you want the text to be multiline instead of singleline?

Answer (score 0):

To make a TextView Scrollable the **setMovementMethod()** has to be called. However, there will be no scroll bar when scrolling it. To add a scroll bar, the **android:scrollbars** attribute has to be set in the layout file like this: